# How do I determine whether Windows 7 is 32-bit or 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, 32-vs-64-bit

I have a Windows 7 computer. How do I determine whether my Windows installation is 32-bit or 64-bit?

Answer (score 2):

Click the **Start** button, then right-click on **Computer** and select **Properties**.

[image: Start > Computer > Properties]

In the window that opens, look for **System type**. This will tell you whether you have a 32-bit or 64-bit operating system installed.

[image: System control panel]